# On register method for outlook-addin meeting/calendar/appointment

Tags: office-js

This is my first time posting here.

I have not seen this anywhere in the Office Add-in api docs but, is there a way to intercept the "register" event on a new calendar/meeting/appointement event in a javascript Add-in ?

I want to send a request to a webserver on register/modification/delete of a calendar/meeting/appointement event inside my add-in but I don't see how I can do it.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Aurelien

Comment: Add-ins are scoped to a single item, so no. You'd need to use Microsoft Graph and register a webhook to fire when their calendar changes. This wouldn't be part of your add-in itself but rather something you web app handles.